# how to fix email template background that works for all and properly

Tags: html-email, email-attachments, email-templates

I have a trouble with email template rendering in gmail account i.e I used background images in email template that are working fine on first render and forwarding too, but when i reply of the same email then background images gone, I could not sort out why this happening either a gmail limitations or something else. Sharing snaps to more clear my problem.

[image: link to image with trouble and requirement]

Comment: Hey man, need to see your code to be able to debug.

Although there isn't necessarily anything we can do to fix your issue. This could be something email clients do, specifically to avoid issues when replying to an email with these elements.

I wouldn't necessarily mark this as a showstopper issue. Responding to an email with these elements and expecting an email to render perfectly, isn't typically the normal use case.

Comment: When forwarded i have a feeling the code gets removed. Gmail is notorious with background images. Search for GANGA Gmail) to see the discussion on social media and websites. I have a feeling that Gmail is removing it and if thats the case there might not be a fix.